# How to put generated artefact into a SVN Tag during running maven-release-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Is there a way to copy a generated Jar File into a SVN tag, which was created by the maven-release-plugin?

And is there a wy to customized the outputname of the generated JAR File in the maven release plugin?

I have figures out that kind o configuration to create a SVN tag:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <tag>${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</tag>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have designed a maven project, that have the feature to create a jar file, if I use the maven command mvn clean install in my local repository. After executing that maven command

Comment: Why would you like to put the generated jar into SVN...SVN is the version control and not an artifact container. In Maven you use usually repository managers for such purposes. Maybe you can elaborate more in detail what you exactly like to achieve?

Comment: First usually you don't need to configure maven-release-plugin in no way (except for multi-module builds). The svn tag will be created during `mvn release:prepare` step. Afterwards you do `mvn release:perform` which really creates the artifacts which is deployed to a maven repository (usually a repository manager like nxus, artifactory or achiva) but it will never be a version control system (git, svn etc.). Furthermore i have doubts that the maven-release-plugin will every be changed in the way you like it.

Comment: The generated output filename is usually like `artifactid-version.ext`. This kind of naming will be used in repository as well and can't be changed cause this would fail maven central a foundation of Maven and other build tools like Gradle/Ivy etc.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could show your full pom file and describe what you like to achieve as i asked you before which you didn't answered.

Comment: The artifact name which is created by maven which is stored as a result can't be changed cause the maven repository based on a naming conventions which can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

These is a difference between source-control-management (SCM, AKA [version control and revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)) and artifacts-repository (AKA [repo-managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository)).

Tools like [Git](http://git-scm.com/), P4, SVN, [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server), SourceSafe etc. are SCM. Meaning they save your sources, keep track of changes and tag (label) your releases (it can tag other things, of course).

In contrary, there are tools like Nexus and Artifactory, which are repositories that store artifacts.

The beauty of maven-release-plugin is that it **builds** your release version, then **tag** the source in the source-control, and then **deploys** the artifact to the repository.

I do not think it is a good practice to store JARs (==artifacts) in the SCM.